# Bash script to create a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, mkdir

I'm messing around with scripting, I am able to create a script which when run prompts me for a name for a new dir, creates it then creates several files, echoes lines out, then deletes it all.

What I would like to do is morph it slightly so it creates and names the directory all by itself!

Seems a pointless exercise I know, but messing around with it is the best way I learn.

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash   
echo "Give a directory name to create:"    
read NEW_DIR    
ORIG_DIR=$(pwd)    
[[ -d $NEW_DIR ]] && echo $NEW_DIR already exists, aborting && exit    
mkdir  $NEW_DIR    
cd $NEW_DIR    
pwd    
for n in 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0    
do        
touch file$n    
done

ls file?    

for names in file?    
do       
echo This file is named $names > $names    
done

cat file?

cd $ORIG_DIR

rm -rf $NEW_DIR

echo "Goodbye"
```

Comment: what do you mean by *it creates and names the directory all by itself*? how will the script choose the names?

Comment: As in instead of me typing a directory name when prompted it's already written in the script.

Comment: do you mean by setting hard-coded value for a directory name in the script (which will replace the *read* operation)?

Comment: Yes, just that!

Comment: You might want to dive into [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and [Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), e. g. `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` in your code can be shortened to `{9..0}` and you might as well replace the whole `for` loop with `touch file{9..0}`.

Comment: if you want to learn something:-) you might want to use `pushd` and `popd` instead of assigning `pwd` to variables. also, in your line `echo This file is named` you should use `>>`, not `>`, if you want to get more than the last line. And maybe `mkdir -p` could help you to avoid the `-d` test. (possibly the `-p` flag is not available everywhere)

Comment: Please get into the habit of quoting your variables. Always. For example, `cd "${NEW_DIR}"`, `[[ -d "${NEW_DIR}" ]]` and `> "${names}"`. This prevents potentially serious errors when variables contain spaces and certain other characters. (The curly brackets are optional except in rare cases.)

Comment: As long as you're playing to learn, `echo -n` prints your prompt without the trailing newline, so you get the cursor after the prompt. I think it looks nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `read` command in order to get the value of`NEW_DIR` from the input, You can set hard-coded value for the *NEW_DIR* variable in the following way:

replace the following line in your script:

```
read NEW_DIR
```

with the following line:

```
NEW_DIR="new_dir_hard_coded_value"
```

> Link for more info about [bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php)

Comment: Thank you! Worked, so simple! Think the search would've been easier with the hard-coded phrase!

Answer (score 6):

If you want a surprise, instead of hardcoding the name you could use a technique to generate a random string, for example

```
NEW_DIR=$(tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w8 | head -n1)
```

This sets `NEW_DIR` to a string of eight alphanumeric characters. Every time you run the script, the new directory will have a different random name...

Or to get a random word, pick a dictionary from `/usr/share/dict/` and use `shuf`, for example:

```
$ shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/british-english
soupier
$ shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/british-english
penguins
```

So

```
NEW_DIR=$(shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/british-english)
mkdir "$NEW_DIR"
...
```

Comment: The command `mktemp -d` creates a temporary directory with a random name in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of prompting for user input, you can hardcode values into scripts by using variable assignment operator (=). Thus, the following two lines,

```
echo "Give a directory name to create:"
read NEW_DIR
```

can be replaced by a single line.

```
NEW_DIR="whatever_name_you_please"
```

---

BTW, I know this is not relevant to the question but in the `for` loop you used in your script, you can write shorthand code for the range. Instead of `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`, you may write it as

```
 for n in {9..0}
```

Comment: no its all relevant thank you, the more see the more I learn!

Answer (score 3):

You could even go one step further: You could tell "read" to offer a proposition for the folder name, accept it by pressing return or change it as you like:

```
read -p "Give a directory name to create: " -ei "default_name" NEW_DIR;
```

this would show a line:

```
Give a directory name to create: default_name
```

To combine with the above suggestions, you could do the following:

```
# pre-set NEW_DIR to a value or to any random string 
# as suggested in the other answers
NEW_DIR="default_name"

# Prompt for new directory name, suggesting previously selected default answer
read -p "Give a directory name to create: " -ei "$NEW_DIR" NEW_DIR;
```

Note that read -p "text" will prompt for the text and ask for the answer in the same line. If you want to stick to your code and have it ask for the 2-line-format you could do

```
echo "Give a directory name to create:"  
read -ei "$NEW_DIR" NEW_DIR
```